# Trying to scrape - no response from XHR

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape http://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/privacy-screen-protectors-us/support/productfinder/ just as a beginning project for me to get my scraping skills up. Was going to use BeautifulSoup/Python to do the job.

When you select a Model (you have to select a Manufacturer first), a request is sent to http://selector.3m.net/_frameurl.php?cid=437&furl=http%253A%2F%2Fselector.3m.net%2Fen_US%2Fi%2Fus.solutions.3m.com , but the Response returned is empty (This request has no response request available).

I'm curious to know more about how/why this happens, for the sake of learning, but obviously I also want to know how to get around it within Python (not using something like Selenium if possible).

CHEERS

EDIT: Presumably it has something to do with the fact that 3M are using an iframe to load their content in

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: I haven't really written any yet, I'm still just exploring it using Dev Tools in chrome

Comment: I've added 2 screenshots to show you what I mean

Comment: The data is retrieved with a get request, look under the doc tab after you select a brand

Comment: The data is retrieved with a get request, look under the doc tab after you select a brand, if you also look under `div class="mmm-manuf-selector"` in developer tools you will see `<a class="list-group-item" onclick="switchmanufacturer(3,437);">
 <b class="list-group-item-heading">Acer</b>
</a>`, the`3,437` are manufacturer id and customer id which are used in the get request, it would probably be possible to parse the `switchmanufacturer(3,437)` and get the data needed for the get request but unfortunately that is dynamically loaded content and does not exist in the source itself.